# Does a "collective" safe haven ETF exist? (e.g. a mix of gold, bonds etc...)

Tags: etf, bonds, gold

In this period of bear market I would like to invest in some safe haven assets, like gold or diamonds for example.

I was wondering if there is an ETF that tracks the price of *a group* of these assets, to just keep my money in *something valuable* over time.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT** from the comments it seems that my question was not clear:  I am not seeking an investment that does not fluctuate (obviously) , I am looking to invest in things that generally and historically are known as "safe haven commodities".

> A safe haven is a type of investment that is expected to retain or increase in value during times of market turbulence. Investors seek out safe havens in order to limit their exposure to losses in the event of market downturns.

[Definition of "safe haven" by Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/safe-haven.asp#:%7E:text=A%20safe%20haven%20is%20a,the%20event%20of%20market%20downturns.)

Comment: while gold and diamonds have significant uses in the industry, what makes you think they'll remain valuable during the market downturn and a global recession (which will affect the industries using them and consumers buying them)?

Comment: @littleadv The fact that they are know as *safe haven assets*.
Which means: assets that have a much more stable value than other investments.